# Como disparar uma função acionando uma rota http get

Tags: javascript, node.js, http-request, websocket

tenho um servidor http e criei um servidor websocket pra rodar junto (igual os videos da rocket).
mas to com dificuldade pra isolar os comandos ... está tudo na página do server.js.
eu queria isolar os comandos que o server envia pro client. Eu tenho um controller que envia dados pro DB (POST request) ... e queria que toda vez que isso acontecesse o servidor enviasse algo pro client websocket....
já tentei de tudo e n to conseguindo usar os comandos websockets sem ser no server.js....

tenho o arquivo server.js:

```
 const { socketController } = require('./controllers/actuator/ActuatorController');


ws.on('request', (request) => {
  const client = request.accept(null, request.origin);

  socketController(client);

  console.log(`${new Date()} IP: ${client.remoteAddress} CONNECTED`);

  client.on('close', () => {
    console.log(`${new Date()} IP: ${client.remoteAddress} DISCONNECTED`);
  });

  
  // reciving client message in console.log
  client.on('message', (message) => {
    if (message.type === 'utf8') {
      console.log(message.utf8Data);
    }
  });
});
```

e o arquivo controller.js

```
socketController(client) {
    client.send('mensagem para o cliente');
  }
```

eu queria criar uma outra função que ao chamar a rota fosse executado o client.send

a imagem sintetiza o que eu gostaria de fazer. obrigado

[image: resumo do que eu gostaria de fazer]

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score -3):

Você pode tentar exportar o "ws" do seu server.js, daí você terá acesso a ele em toda a aplicação, depois no seu controller você importa ele.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).